# Intent causes force close in android app (O'reilly video tutorial)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have been following a video tutorial from O'reilly media going through the basics of android. The app is a `flashlight` and it's only supposed to switch between two activities with the use of a button. But the app force close when i call `startActivity(intent)` in `RedFlashlightActivity.java`, the intent is only supposed to change activity. Eclipse does not recognice any errors either.

My thanks for any help!

I put the code in pastebin as I tought it would clog upp the post.

**RedFlashlightActivity.java**
http://pastebin.com/4ejjgaXp

**GreenFlashlightActivity.java**
http://pastebin.com/SdGV32kL

**Manifest**
http://pastebin.com/qjRACKix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your `manifest`:

```
android:name=".GreenFlashligtActivity"
```

should be

```
android:name=".GreenFlashlightActivity"
```

Therefore the new Activity could not be started, because it was not found,and the App crashes.